I am the owner of an image. I published it in Unsplash. Am I allowed to upload that same image to other sites?
Unsplash makes it clear that as a user of the site, I cannot just download a random image and  "replicate a similar or competing service".
However, I am the photographer & owner of the image. I just gave Unsplash a license to use that image.
So, can I upload that same image to another site (say, Wikimedia Commons) with another license? And if so, what license should I choose?
I have read https://unsplash.com/terms but I am still confused about this use case.

The relevant section appears to be section 6 of the terms, which indicates your license grant to Unsplash is non-exclusive, meaning you retain copyright ownership of uploads and are free to relicence the image to another service:

6 User Content
YOU OWN ALL OF YOUR USER CONTENT, INCLUDING ANY IMAGES THAT YOU UPLOAD TO THE SITE. [...]
B. Limited License to Us. You grant us a worldwide, non-exclusive [emphasis mine], royalty-free license (with the right to sublicense) [...]

The "competing service" clause appears to apply to use of images of a licensee, where you are not the original owner of the image. The FAQ indicates two situations where it would apply, but there is no reason why it would apply to you as the licensor, given the license is explicitly non-exclusive and not an exclusive or sole license.


Mass scraping or crawling images from Unsplash and using those images to build a site just like Unsplash where your users could download, copy, modify, distribute or use images originally found on Unsplash, for personal or commercial use.
Using Unsplash content to submit it as your own on any other image sharing or stock image website;


The rest of section 5 also indicates rights you would have as a licensee of the images. As the original owner of the image, you have no need to receive a license to reuse your own image.
However, some services, such as Wikimedia Commons, might be concerned that they are unable to verify that you are the original photographer of the image. It is a requirement on Commons for images uploaded on or after the 5th of June 2017 (when Unsplash changed from a CC-0 licence) to undergo a license review process (see Template:Unsplash and the August 2017 discussion that put the process in place).
Commons does have processes for confirming the licenses of images previously published on other websites (see for example Commons:But it's my own work!) which usually involves a statement indicating dual licensing under a compatible free license (such as CC BY-SA, CC BY or CC0). You can see an example of a copyright waiver in the description in this Unsplash image, though it is up to the other service you're uploading to to determine whether they'd accept any specific release as sufficient. If this is something that you plan on doing a lot, it is probably going to be less hassle to upload to the service that has the least restrictive licensing conditions first, and then reuploading to any other services you want to after.
As for which license to choose, Commons has three CC licenses as the most common (CC BY-SA 4.0, CC BY 4.0 and CC0) depending on whether you want people to attribute you when reusing your work and whether derivatives should be distributed under the same license. The GNU Free Documentation License and the Free Art License are also sometimes used. There is also a guide at Commons:Choosing a license which has more information, and any other service that offers choice between multiple licenses may provide similar information.

I can only get to the German version of the terms, but I'm assuming the English ones are similar. The text reads (emphasis mine):

Diese Lizenz beinhaltet jedoch nicht das Recht, Bilder von Unsplash zusammenzustellen, um einen ähnlichen oder konkurrierenden Service zu replizieren.


This license does not include the right, to collect images from Unsplash to provide a similiar or competing service.

This means that you must not take a considerable number of pictures from Unsplash and create your own "my-unsplash.com" website. You can take individual pictures and use them for whatever you want (including uploading them to other websites), but not a collection of images. Of course, that also applies to your own images. So you can clearly upload your own images also to Wikimedia Commons or similar websites. The license also does not prevent you from selling any of your own images to a newspaper, for instance (but it forbids selling images of others in such a way).
